# Take time to load image in imageview in custom info window adapter

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

I am using picasso to load the image in info window adapter but it take time to load in imageview . any one help me to load the image quickly on clicking on the marker.

Comment: You can use Glide to load image quickly.https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: you can use progressbar until image not shown in imageview

Comment: Kindly post your code portion where you are facing the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have done it through glide .when glide callback return the response then show again info window and hide previous info window.
just using this code i complete it:

```
  Glide.with(getActivity())
                        .load(getMarkerDetails(marker).get("imageUrl"))
                        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                if (marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                                    marker.hideInfoWindow();
                                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .into(img_profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fresco to load image quickly and while image is not loaded you can put placeholder so it will look good as compare to now.

Answer (score 0):

Best Practices is if your images are too large then use **Thumbnail** images for faster loading in recyclerview.

*(In webapi response there are two URL one is original images url and other is thumbnail(small) image url)*

After clicking on image load original large images.

Hope this may help you :)